# how to factor dao with class parameter

Tags: java, class, reflection, factory

I want to create a Factory which returns dao-instance, depending on the Class clazz

Teammember, Scene and Equipment are my Model Classes.

My DAO's look like this:

```
public class JDBCTeammemberDAO implements JdbcDAO<Teammember>
```

my Factory looks like this:

```
public class DAOFactory {

    JdbcDAO createDAO(Class clazz) {
        if(clazz.equals(Teammember.class)) {
            return new JDBCTeammemberDAO();
        }
        if(clazz.equals(Scene.class)) {
            return new JDBCSceneDAO();
        }
        if(clazz.equals(Equipment.class)) {
            return new JDBCEquipmentDAO();
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

I was thinking about switch and polymorphism, but I couldn't figure out how.

Basically I want to find the Implementation "SomeClass implements JdbcDAO"

My first approach was:

```
String name = clazz.getName().substring(6); // model.Teammember
Class<?> forName;
try {
    forName = Class.forName("dao.jdbc.JDBC" + name + "DAO");
    return (JdbcDAO) forName.newInstance();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I don't feel good with handling this with String method. Besides, it doesn't work, if I have different Model and Dao names (like: JDBCMemberDAO instead of JDBCTeammemberDAO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar situation and decided to use a Dao registry to handle the issue.  Using the generic dao pattern @Perception mentioned:

```
public interface JdbcDAO<T> {
    T find(Long id) ;
    T create(T entity);
    T update(T entity);
    void delete(T entity);
}

public class JdbcDAOImpl<T> {
    this.clazz = clazz;
    DaoRegistry.register (clazz, this);
}
```

Then you can have your

```
   public class JDBCTeammemberDAO extend JdbcDAOImpl<TeamMember> {
       public class JDBCTeammemberDAO () {
          super(TeamMember.class);
       }
   }
```

DaoRegistry would look something like this:

```
public class DaoRegistry {
        private Map<Class, JdbcDAO> daoMap;

        public synchronized void register (Class type, JdbcDao dao) {
                if (!daoMap.containsKey(type))
                     daoMap.put (type, dao);
                else
                     logger.error ("Something is really wrong because you are creating another dao for this class.", e);

            }

        public JdbcDAO get(Class type) {return daoMap.get(type);
}
```

This is just the jest of it, you will need to make sure it is thread-safe.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sormula works as you describe. It provides a method to get the "DAO" for a row/record class. See `database.getTable(Inventory.class);` in [example 1](http://www.sormula.org/example1/). You don't need to write any DAO's.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a slight redesign, this problem is easy enough to solve with a little bit of Generics and Polymorphism:

```
public interface JdbcDAO<T> {
    T find(Long id) ;
    T create(T entity);
    T update(T entity);
    void delete(T entity);

    // Other common definitions
}

public class JdbcDAOImpl<T> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public JdbcDAOImpl() {
        super();
    }

    protected JdbcDAOImpl(Class<T> clazz) {
        super();
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    // Common implementation here
}

public class EquipmentDAO extends JdbcDAOImpl<Equipment> {
    public EquipmentDAO() {
        super(Equipment.class);
    }

    // Subclass specific implementation here
}
```

Rinse and repeat the specific impl for each of your Models and instantiate them directly (without use of a factory).

Comment: but how do I get the right DAO? By using `JdbcDAOImpl<Equipment> equipmentDao = new JdbcDAOImpl<Equipment>()`  ? I want a factory for my service Class, which shouldn't care which one it gets. (especially if I want to mock it)

Comment: If having a factory is core to your design then the above code will not help you. But then I also question why you need Model specific DAO's as well.

Comment: It's not my core. I need a way to mock/stub my Service-Classes. We learned it with factories only at school - if you have any better idea I'm up to you.